# When asking if someone agrees or not with one word, do you say "agreed" or "agree"?

Tags: past-tense, adjectives

I've watched a few televised court cases. I distinctly hear the lawyers, when examining the witnesses, say with one word "agreed" and not "agree"?

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

Either, depending on what you mean. You can use "agree?" to mean "Do you agree?" or use "agreed?" to mean "Are we agreed?"

Answer (score 0):

In a formal situation, such as a meeting, when signifying one's agreement to something, it is usual to say "agreed".

Though if one is simply responding to something someone has said "I agree" is more the usual confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if someone agrees with you then it is...'Agree?'
The use of 'Agreed' in this instance seems to anticipate the other party agreeing with you, as if you are speaking for that person. In the former case you are asking that person explicitly.
I would say both are correct. However there are subtle differences.
'Agree?' Is a direct question put to someone.
'Agreed?' Has a subtle sense of trying to get you to agree, by presupposing it, as if to say...."Come on, you agree with that don't you?"
or another way of saying...."I take it you also agree?" Has both question and statement together.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).